# Why does a Azure Cosmos query sorting by timestamp (string) cost so much more than by _ts (built in)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

**This query cost 265 RU/s**:

`SELECT top 1 * FROM c 
WHERE c.CollectPackageId = 'd0613cbb-492b-4464-b66b-3634b5571826'
ORDER BY c.StartFetchDateTimeUtc DESC`

**StartFetchDateTimeUtc** is a string property, serialized by using the Cosmos API

**This query cost 5 RU/s**:

`SELECT top 1 * FROM c 
WHERE c.CollectPackageId = 'd0613cbb-492b-4464-b66b-3634b5571826'
ORDER BY c._ts DESC`

**_ts** is a built in field, a Unix-based numeric timestamp.

**Example result** (only including this field and _ts):

`"StartFetchDateTimeUtc": "2017-08-08T03:35:04.1654152Z",
"_ts": 1502163306`

**The index** is in place and follows the suggestions & tutorials how to configure a sortable string/timestamp. It looks like:

    `{
      "path": "/StartFetchDateTimeUtc/?",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": -1
        }
      ]
    }`

Answer (score 3):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations), the **"Item size,Item property count,Data consistency,Indexed properties,Document indexing,Query patterns,Script usage"** variables will affect the RU.

So it is very strange that different property costs different RU.

I also create a test demo on my side(with your index and same document property). I have inserted 1000 records to the documentdb. The two different query costs same RU. I suggest you could start a new collection and test again.

The result is like this:

Order by StartFetchDateTimeUtc

[image]

Order by _ts

[image]

Comment: This is so weird. We cannot start a new collection because this is production data. What happened is this:
* The collection was populated WITHOUT the UtcTimeStamp property, with 10 000 documents
* Afterwards, the property was added, and an Index as well.
* Then, you can see this problem.

By the way, thanks a TON for the detailed response! Owe you big time. We're close to opening a support ticket to Microsoft because of this grand weirdness. It has a huge impact on what we pay for consuming databases.

Comment: @imbageek, did this get resolved?  I'm seeing a similar issue; 8.5 RU without sort, 22.4 RU with sort of indexed dateTime field, 8.8 RU when sorted with _ts.

Comment: @brudert unfortunately no I didn´t. Lemme know if you know why. :)